# Probabilistic Density

Tags: probability, density-function

Variable $X$ has the following probability density:

$f(x) =$\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{x ∉ [0,2]} \\
kx(2-x), & \text{x ∈ [0,2]}
\end{cases}

How can I find the parameter $k$ so $f(x)$ is a probability density function?
How can I simulate variable $X$?

Comment: The parameter $k$ is a normalizing constant and you need the density to integrate to one, so...

Comment: I suggest you add `self-study` as a tag of your question.

Comment: Is this for some subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compute
$$\int_0^2 kz(2-z)dz=1$$
to find the parameter $k$.

For the simulation you can use the inversion method.